# approximating a variety locally by a vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose we have $m$ homogeneous equations with integer coefficients in $n$ variables and that $m >> n$. Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Question 1: is there a way to approximate the variety defined by these equations around $x_0$ by a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

An idea: one can linearize the $m$ equations around $x_0$ and subsequently approximate the variety by the subspace of solutions of the resulting system of equations. The problem that i have with this approach is that, since $m >> n$, it is likely that the resulting linear system of equations will be inconsistent.

Question 2: Is there any rigorous algebraic-geometric approach towards fixing this problem?

Question 3: Is the dimension of the ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by the equations, related in any way with the possible dimension of the approximating subspace around $x_0$?

Ideas from dimension theory are very welcome.

Comment: The resulting linear system of equations can't be inconsistent because $x_0$ will be a solution. Anyway, the keyword you want is "Zariski tangent space."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Why will $x_0$ be a solution? I am not assuming that $x_0$ is in the variety of the original equations. $x_0$ is just a random point. Thanks for the keyword though.

Comment: Oh. Why would you want to take $x_0$ to be a random point?

Comment: I am trying to solve a constrained optimization problem via an iterative procedure. The constraints are precisely these equations. The sequence generated by this procesure is not necessarily feasible (i.e. its points lie in general outside the variety of the equation constraints). But i want to approximate the constraints locally with a subspace, and use this subspace to reduce the dimension of the original problem (locally).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Is the concept of Zariski tangent space only applicable to point belonging to the variety?

Comment: Yes. It hadn't occurred to me that you would be looking at a point not in the variety. I think this is a strange thing to do.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: there are marvelous things in mathematics that have evolved from strange ideas. So, i am taking your remark as a compliment :)